# Is it possible to modify a variable in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm using Postman and I am trying to chain together some requests. There is an identity string that is generated in my first request that I would like to use in my second request e.g. similar to searching for a product, and then adding that product to basket.

Now I've been able to pull the value from the first request and I can pick that up in the second request. The problem is that the identity string has an ampersand in it. When I post the second request, it throws an error because the ampersand has not been escaped in the string. I would like to replace the ampersand in the variable with "&" but I can't get this to work.

I'm new to JavaScript so I imagine this is where the problem is. In Postman I have:

`var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(jsonObject);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ItineraryId", jsonObject.ItineraryId);
ItineraryId.replace("&","&amp;");`

This returns "There was an error in evaluating the test script:  ItineraryId is not defined". So I tried:

`var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(jsonObject);
var oldId = postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ItineraryId", jsonObject.ItineraryId);
oldId.replace("&","&amp;");`

And got "There was an error in evaluating the test script:  Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it maybe something to do with the type (if that's the correct terminology...). I added to my test: `var oldStr = "identity&string";
var str = oldStr.replace("&","&amp;");
tests["Is string escaped correctly?"] = str === "identity&amp;string";` which works as expected (if I remove the `amp;` from the result, the test fails).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out!

`var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log(jsonObject);
var itineraryId = jsonObject.ItineraryId;
itineraryId = itineraryId.replace("&","&amp;");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ItineraryId", itineraryId);`

Answer (score 0):

You should user `pm.collectionVariables.set` like in example below :

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("userId", pm.response.headers.get('Location').replace(pm.environment.get("api_url") + "/api/users/", ""));
```

In this example after POST on `/api/users` in response header : `Location` we receive link to new resource. You can use other variables like : `pm.environment.get("api_url")`